# Find coordinates within radius around many starting points in grid

Tags: r

I have a grid of 10x10m coordinates that I extracted from a raster. I have a set of 'starting points'. For each starting point, I want to find the location (coordinates) of cells within a 10-50m radius around it.

I am aware of functions to do this with a raster starting point, but additional analyses that I have not included here require that I perform the search from a grid of coordinates in the format shown below.

The code below achieves my aim, however the `outer` function produces vectors that are far too large (> 10 Gb) on my actual dataset (which is a grid of 9 million 10x10m cells, with 3000 starting points).

I am looking for alternatives that achieve the same result as the following (simplified) code, but do not require large vector storage or looping over each starting point separately.

```
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)

#Set up the mock raster
orig=raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
res(orig)=10
vals <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2), times = c(72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72))
setValues(orig, vals)
values(orig) <- vals
xygrid <- as.data.frame(orig, xy = TRUE) %>% .[,1:2]
head(xygrid)

     x  y
1 -175 85
2 -165 85
3 -155 85
4 -145 85
5 -135 85
6 -125 85

#the initial starting points
init_locs <- c(5, 10, 15, 20)

#calculate the distance to every surrounding cell from starting point
Rx <- outer(xygrid[init_locs, 1], xygrid[, 1], "-")
Ry <- outer(xygrid[init_locs, 2], xygrid[, 2], "-")
R <- sqrt(Rx^2+Ry^2) #overall distance 

  
for (i in 1:length(R[,1])) { 
  expr2 <- (R[i,] > 10 & R[i,] <= 50) #extract the location of cells within 10-50m
  inv <- xygrid[expr2,] #extract the coordinates of these cells
}

head(inv)

     x  y
15 -35 85
16 -25 85
17 -15 85
18  -5 85
22  35 85
23  45 85
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to compute the Euclidian distances between all points, using the `dist()` function (`distmat=as.matrix(dist(values))`). You will get a matrix of distances from which you can extract the values from any given row or column to find out which points are close to a specific point (e.g. `close.to.3 = (1:length(values))[distmat[,3]<50]` would result in a vector of indices of the points that have a distance below 50 to point 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data --- you were using a lon/lat example, but based on your code, I am assuming that you are using planar data.

```
library(raster)   
r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100, xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r) # for display only
xygrid <- as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE)[,1:2]
locs <- c(8025, 1550, 5075)

dn <- 2.5 # min dist
dx <- 5.5 # max dist
```

The simplest approach would be to use `pointDistance`

```
p <- xyFromCell(r, locs)
d <- pointDistance(xygrid, p, lonlat=FALSE)
u <- unique(which(d>dn & d<dx) %% nrow(d))
pts <- xygrid[u,]

plot(r)
points(pts)
```

But you will probably run out of memory with that, and it is inefficient to compute all distance. Instead, you may intersect the points with a buffer around the points of interest

```
b1 <- buffer(SpatialPoints(p, proj4string=crs(r)), dx)
b2 <- buffer(SpatialPoints(p, proj4string=crs(r)), dn)
b <- erase(b1, b2)
x <- intersect(SpatialPoints(xygrid, proj4string=crs(r)), b)

plot(r)
points(x, cex=.5)
points(xyFromCell(r, locs), col="red", pch="x")
```

With `terra` it goes like this -- and works well for large datasets in version 1.1-11 that should be on CRAN this week

```
library(terra)
rr <- rast(r)
pp <- xyFromCell(rr, locs)
bb1 <- buffer(vect(pp), dx)
bb2 <- buffer(vect(pp), dn)
bb <- erase(bb1, bb2)
xx <- intersect(vect(as.matrix(xygrid)), bb)
```

You can do similar things with `sf`.

Given that you have so many data points, you might want to start with removing all points that are clearly not of interest

```
xySel <- lapply(locs, function(i) {
        xy <- xygrid[i,]
        s <- xygrid[,1] > xy[,1]-dx & xygrid[,1] < xy[,1]+dx & xygrid[,2] > xy[,2]-dx & xygrid[,2] < xy[,2]+dx
        xygrid[s,]
    })

  xySel = do.call(rbind, xySel)
  dim(xySel)
  # [1] 363   2
  dim(xygrid)
  #[1] 10000     2
```

And now you could run `pointDistance` as above on all data (or else inside the lapply function)

You say that you need to use points, and not a raster. I have seen that idea many times, and 9 out of 10 times that is wrong. Maybe it is true in your case. For others who stumble upon this question, here are are two raster based approaches.

With the raster package you could use `extract( ... ,cellnumbers=TRUE)` or `adjacent`. With adjacent, you would first make a weights matrix using one of the buffers made above

```
buf <- disaggregate(b)[2,]
rb <- crop(r, buf)
w <- as.matrix(rasterize(buf, rb, background=NA) )
w[6,6]=0
```

And then use the weight matrix like this

```
a <- adjacent(r, locs, w, pairs=FALSE)

pts <- xyFromCell(r, a)   
plot(r)
points(pts)
```

With `terra` you could use the `cells` method

```
d <- cells(rr, bb)
xy <- xyFromCell(rr, d[,2])
plot(rr)
points(xy, cex=.5)
lines(bb, col="red", lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

(Raster and spatial data are not my specialty, but this made me think of a naive approach that might work acceptably. I don't know anything about the methods @Robert Hijmans mentioned, those are likely much more performant. I just thought this sounded like an interesting question to explore with basic methods.)`</caveat>`

## Approach

The main challenge here is you have 9 million cells, but only around 80 of those will be with 50m of any given point. If you calculate all those cells' distances to 3,000 starting points and then filter for those under 50m, that's 9M x 3k = 27 billion calculations, and a gigantic data structure, almost all of which is unnecessary.

We can quickly get ~1,000x more efficient by splitting this into two problems -- first, what general region of potentially-within-50m-points should we look at, and second, what is the actual distance to the points in those regions?

We can precalculate a modestly sized <2MB hash table for step 1. Then, by joining it to our locations (a very fast operation), we can focus our calculations on the 1/1000th of points that have a chance of being within 50m. I arbitrarily split the original cells into 100 x 100 = 10k sectors, each sector holding 30x30 cells.

### 1. Creating hash table

For the hash table, I'll assign each point to a sector, somewhat arbitrarily as 30x30 cells, so we have 100x100 = 10k sectors. This could be tuned based on speed vs. memory tradeoffs.

```
max_dist = 30                   # sector width, in cells
xygrid2 <- expand_grid(
  x = seq(0, 2999, by = 1),     # 3000x3000 location grid
  y = seq(0, 2999, by = 1))    
xygrid2$sector_x = xygrid2$x %/% max_dist    # 100 x 100 sectors
xygrid2$sector_y = xygrid2$y %/% max_dist
y_range = max(xygrid2$sector_y) + 1
xygrid2$sector_num = xygrid2$sector_x*y_range + xygrid2$sector_y
```

We now have 10,000 sectors assigned. Now which sectors are adjacent to which others? In every case, the adjacent sectors follow the same pattern. In this case, I have 100 sectors across x, so the sectors adjacent to sector S will have sector numbers that vary from S by  `-101 -100  -99   -1    0    1   99  100  101`. We can use this pattern to assign all the adjacencies instantaneously. For simplicity, I leave in sectors outside our range; they will be ignored later anyway.

```
sector_num_deltas <- rep(-1:1, by = 3) + rep(-1:1, each = 3) * y_range
distinct(xygrid2, sector_num) %>%
  uncount(9) %>%       # copy each row 9 times, one for each adjacency 
  mutate(sector_num_adj = sector_num + sector_num_deltas) -> adjacencies
```

### 2. Join and calculate

Now that we have that, the rest goes much faster, since we can do the calculations only on the 1/1000th of sectors that are nearby. With that, we can now identify the 240,000 points that are within 50m of the 3,000 starting positions in under 4 seconds:

```
# Here are 3,000 random starting locations
set.seed(42)
sample_starts <- xygrid2 %>%
  slice_sample(n = 3000) %>%
  mutate(sample_num = row_number())


# Join each location to all the adjacent sectors, and then add all the 
#  locations within those sectors, and then calculate distances.
sample_starts %>%    # 3,000 starting points...

  # join each position to the nine adjacent sectors = ~27,000 rows
  left_join(adjacencies, by = "sector_num") %>%

  # join each sector to the (30x30 = 900) cells in those sectors --> 24 million rows
  # That's a lot, but it's only 1/1000th of the starting problem with 
  # 3k x 9M = 27 billion comparisons!
  left_join(xygrid2, by = c("sector_num_adj" = "sector_num")) %>%
  

  select(-contains("sector")) %>%
  mutate(dist = sqrt((x.x-x.y)^2 + (y.x-y.y)^2)) %>%
  filter(dist <= 5) -> result
```

The result tells us that our 3,000 sample starting points are within 5 decimeters (50m) of 242,575 cells, about 80 for each starting point.

```
result
# A tibble: 242,575 x 6
     x.x   y.x sample_num   x.y   y.y  dist
   <dbl> <dbl>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1069   140          1  1064   140  5   
 2  1069   140          1  1065   137  5   
 3  1069   140          1  1065   138  4.47
 4  1069   140          1  1065   139  4.12
 5  1069   140          1  1065   140  4   
 6  1069   140          1  1065   141  4.12
 7  1069   140          1  1065   142  4.47
 8  1069   140          1  1065   143  5   
 9  1069   140          1  1066   136  5   
10  1069   140          1  1066   137  4.24
# … with 242,565 more rows
```

---

Here's a sample to see how that's working in a small corner of our data:

```
ggplot(a %>% mutate(sample_grp = sector_num_adj %% 8 %>% as.factor), 
       aes(x.y, y.y, color = sample_grp)) +
  geom_point(data = adjacencies %>% filter(sector_num_adj == 5864) %>%
               left_join(xygrid2) %>% distinct(x, y, sector_num),
             color = "gray80", shape = 21,
             aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = adjacencies %>% filter(sector_num == 5864) %>%
               left_join(xygrid2) %>% distinct(x, y, sector_num),
             color = "gray70", shape = 21,
             aes(x, y)) +
  annotate("text", alpha = 0.5,
           x = c(1725, 1750),
           y = c(1960, 1940),
           label = c("Lookup area", "sector of\nstarting location")) +
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  coord_equal() -> my_plot


library(gganimate)
animate(
  my_plot + 
    gganimate::view_zoom_manual(pan_zoom = -1, ease = "quadratic-in-out",
      xmin = c(0, 1700),
      xmax = c(3000, 1800),
      ymin = c(0, 1880),
      ymax = c(3000, 1980)), 
  duration = 3, fps = 20, width = 300)
```

[image]

Comment: very cool --- similar to what I show with lapply, but your animation takes the cake!