Filtering for a Large Dataset within a 2000-Meter Radius from Grid Points
I have a huge data frame of 13170180 rows, and I have a grid of 1107650 points. I want to filter data points based on a 2000-meter radius from the center of each grid point.
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)
library(ratser)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)  

# Define the resolution of the grid (in degrees)
grid_resolution <- 1 / 60  # 1 arc-minute resolution

# Create an empty raster grid with the specified extent and resolution
grid <- raster(xmn = xmin, xmx = xmax, ymn = ymin, ymx = ymax, 
               resolution = grid_resolution, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# Extract grid cell centers (midpoints)
grid_centers <- coordinates(grid)

# Convert to a data frame for easy manipulation
grid_points<- data.frame(grid_centers)
colnames(grid_points) <- c("long_center", "lat_center")

# Define the radius for filtering (2000 meters)
radius <- 2000

# Initialize an empty list to store the points within 2000m for each grid center
points_within_2000m_list <- vector("list", nrow(grid_points))

# Use pblapply to loop through each grid center with a progress bar
points_within_2000m_list <- pblapply(1:nrow(grid_points), function(i) {
  # Extract the grid center coordinates (latitude and longitude)
  target_lat <- grid_points[i, 2]
  target_long <- grid_points[i, 1]
  
  # Calculate the distance between each data point and the current grid center
  data$distance <- distHaversine(
    matrix(c(data$long, data$lat), ncol = 2),
    matrix(c(target_long, target_lat), ncol = 2)
  )
  
  # Filter data points within 2000 meters of the current grid center
  points_within_2000m <- data %>%
    filter(distance <= radius)
  
  # Return the filtered points
  return(points_within_2000m)
})

# Now, `points_within_2000m_list` contains a list of data frames, 
# where each data frame holds the points within 2000 meters of each grid center

Running this code will take 28 days to complete. Is there any way of running it faster?

First filter on a square using vectorized coordinates. Then limit to the desired circle. Sounds like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847903/find-coordinates-within-radius-around-many-starting-points-in-grid?rq=2

What's the domain, wildlife migration? What about spatial extent, i.e. your xmin .. ymax values for the grid? And grid resolution? Are those points in df scattered around the globe or fit into some smaller region / country / 1-2 UTM zones? Does your dataframe includes some details other than coordinates, e,g,  admin. units, countries, continents? Can you provide some code to generate example data? Requirements for precision? You choose distHaversine over  e.g. distGeo & distVincentyEllipsoid, would a distance calculated on a projected coordinate system also be close enough?

This dataset contains height measurements associated with latitude and longitude coordinates.
The xmin and xmax parameters are not critical for this analysis. You can choose any extent of fine resolution to have a huge grid point size.
The objective is to filter the data to include only the entries that fall within a
radius of 2000 meters from each grid point.  I tried distHaversine each points took 5 min I have 1107650 points so can you imagine how many days are needed ?

Must say I missed 1/60 grid_resolution. Just for reference, gird cell at equator would be  ~ 1850m x 1850m, at Latitude 60 it's around ~ 926m x 1850m

xmin = 80°E and xmax = 100° E, ymin = 2°N and ymax = 25°N

Your example does not work. Can you please edit your code so that it runs (for a small example dataset)?

Not a complete answer, but I would like to suggest sf::st_intersects() function to find a list of points within buffers.
Creating the raster as starting point for grid.
grid_resolution <- 1 / 60
grid <- terra::rast(xmin = 0, xmax = 4, ymin = 0, ymax = 4, 
               resolution = grid_resolution, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
terra::values(grid) <- 1:terra::ncell(grid)

Now, creating buffers around every raster cell grid:
radius <- 2000

b <- as.data.frame(grid, xy = TRUE)[, 1:2] |>
  terra::vect(geom = c("x", "y"), crs = terra::crs(grid)) |>
  terra::buffer(radius)

Now, a sample points instead of your data frame, but you can create your own in {sf} package using sf::st_as_sf(df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = ...).
points <- terra::spatSample(grid, size = 40000,
                method = "random", xy=TRUE)
points$lyr.1 <- row.names(points)
p <- terra::vect(points, geom = c("x", "y"), crs = terra::crs(grid))

terra::plot(grid)
terra::points(points, cex = 0.1, pch = 10)


Now a bit of {sf} package: we are converting buffers and sample points to sf objects and run intersects() to get the list of intersecting objects:
b_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(b)
p_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(p)

tictoc::tic()
l_sf <- sf::st_intersects(b_sf, p_sf)
tictoc::toc()
#> 10.082 sec elapsed

l_sf
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 57600, where the
#> predicate was `intersects'
#> first 10 elements:
#>  1: (empty)
#>  2: 1338, 18981
#>  3: 1338, 16901, 20448
#>  4: 1338, 15566, 20448
#>  5: 20448
#>  6: 7345, 34196
#>  7: 4603, 7345, 14446
#>  8: 4603, 7345, 22396
#>  9: 4603, 32411
#>  10: 1159, 30164, 32411

10 sec for 50+ k buffers, not bad on lazy laptop. l_sf[1] is empty, l_sf[2] contains points 1338 and 18981 etc. And sample plot for buffer No. 1016 which contains 5 points:
terra::plot(grid, 
            xlim = c(sf::st_bbox(b_sf[1016, ,])$xmin[[1]]-0.02, sf::st_bbox(b_sf[1016, ,])$xmax[[1]]+0.02),
            ylim = c(sf::st_bbox(b_sf[1016, ,])$ymin[[1]]-0.02, sf::st_bbox(b_sf[1016, ,])$ymax[[1]]+0.02))

b_sf |>
  terra::plot(add = TRUE, lwd=0.5, lty = 3)
b_sf[1016, ,] |>
  terra::plot(add = TRUE, lwd = 2)

p_sf |>
  subset(lyr.1 %in% l_sf[1016][[1]]) |>
  terra::plot(add = TRUE, pch = 10, col = "red")


You can search points for each buffer with {terra} as well, but in my tests it takes a bit longer (by magnitude or so)
l <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(b)), function(x) terra::values(terra::intersect(p, b[x, ]))[, 1])

For further time reduction I would suggest to divide the grid and data points to smaller (overlapping by at least 2000 m) chunks and try {future} package or just few more R sessions at the same time.
Created on 2024-10-14 with reprex v2.1.0

It worked, and it took me 3 days to do the intersecting. I am using the PC of the following specifications:
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-14900   2.00 GHz
Installed RAM 128 GB (128 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Glad it helped.
